# How do I connect a keyboard shortcut to a text box?

Tags: winforms, textbox, keyboard-shortcuts

I have two labels:

"Source Directory:" & "Target Directory:"

and two text boxes:

"tbSource" & "tbTarget"

I have added a shortcut to each text box

"Alt + S" & "Alt + T"

This works fine, but if I try to add underscores to the labels

"&Source..." & "&Target..."

it breaks down. With the underscores only the first text box (tbSource) is ever selected. (With both shortcuts)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Since your Labels use mnemonics, you just need to make sure that the `TabIndex` of your TextBoxes is set to the related Label's `TabIndex` + 1. -- *underscore* means *ampersand* (`&`) here, right?

Comment: How have you added _"shortcut to each text box"_? Your questions is namely _"How do I connect a keyboard shortcut to a text box?"_

Comment: Thanks Jimi. Now I feel stupid, it's so obvious now that I have seen the light...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jimi's answer is correct:

"Since your Labels use mnemonics, you just need to make sure that the TabIndex of your TextBoxes is set to the related Label's TabIndex + 1."